# Auto-capitalize ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Category model which name's needs to not be capitalized.

I need for it's first letter to be capitalized when it's rendered in the template with ModelChoiceField.

Since I can't do `{{ form|capfirst }}`, how should I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lower](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#lower):

```
{{ form|lower|capfirst }}
```

Or you can override the `__init__` method of your form. Something like this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].label_from_instance = obj.category.capitalize()
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant is that when I save it, it can't have capitalized letters. So all categories are like "example" as opposed to "Example". However, I need it to be shown as "Example" when the ModelChoiceField is rendered in the template.